# how to use a symbolfile with cortex M3?

Tags: gcc, ld, cortex-m

I am trying to use a symbolfile to link a program on CortexM3.  The 'program' runs in RAM and uses statically-bound functions from ROM.  So I use a symbolfile to identify the address of all ROM functions.

The problem is that gcc seems to think that all functions in the symbolfile are ARM32 rather than Thumb and so I end up with a thumb->arm32 conversion (which of course crashes since the M3 doesn't support ARM32 instructions)

test.c:

```
extern void tfunc();
int main()
{
    tfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

symbolfile:

```
tfunc = 0x08011029;
```

compile:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -c test.c
arm-none-eabi-ld test.o --just-symbols=symbolfile
```

Results in code like:

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -d a.out 

a.out:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <main>:
    8000:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
    8002:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
    8004:   f000 e804   blx 8010 <__tfunc_from_thumb>
    8008:   2300        movs    r3, #0
    800a:   4618        mov r0, r3
    800c:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
    800e:   bf00        nop

00008010 <__tfunc_from_thumb>:
    8010:   e51ff004    ldr pc, [pc, #-4]   ; 8014 <__tfunc_from_thumb+0x4>
    8014:   08011029    .word   0x08011029
```

note that the 'blx' call is to a even address whereas the M3 spec mandates all jumps are to an odd (thumb) address

I found a solution of sorts online using the assembler instead of a symbolfile:
sym.s:

```
    .global tfunc
    .type tfunc %function
    .equ    tfunc, 0x08011029
```

and building with:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -c test.c
arm-none-eabi-as -o sym.o sym.s
arm-none-eabi-ld test.o sym.o
```

Which generates a (rather verbose, butat least functionally correct veneer):

```
00008000 <main>:
    8000:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
    8002:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
    8004:   f000 f804   bl  8010 <__tfunc_veneer>
    8008:   2300        movs    r3, #0
    800a:   4618        mov r0, r3
    800c:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
    800e:   bf00        nop

00008010 <__tfunc_veneer>:
    8010:   b401        push    {r0}
    8012:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (801c <__tfunc_veneer+0xc>)
    8014:   4684        mov ip, r0
    8016:   bc01        pop {r0}
    8018:   4760        bx  ip
    801a:   bf00        nop
    801c:   08011029    .word   0x08011029
```

I found I can work around this with long calls by adding '#pragma long_calls' to the top of my c code.

However, my question isn't how to get my code to build properly, it is how to use a symbolfile with a CortexM, as there are cases where the #pragma doesn't work, and while the assembly option would be feasible, it makes the build system significantly more complex

Answer (score 0):

> note that the 'blx' call is to a even address

These functions are generated by the linker `ld`.

> `arm-none-eabi-ld test.o --just-symbols=symbolfile`

You must tell `arm-none-eabi-ld` that you want to generate thumb code. Using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` as frontend for linking is usually simpler.